# Problem with rospack depends1

Tags: ros-melodic, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and using ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04. I was following the tutorials and got stuck with the command `rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials`

I am getting this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/rospack.py", line 59, in init_rospack_interface
    lookup = _get_default_RosdepLookup(Options())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 130, in _get_default_RosdepLookup
    verbose=options.verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 633, in create_default
    sources = load_cached_sources_list(sources_cache_dir=sources_cache_dir, verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 533, in load_cached_sources_list
    return parse_sources_data(cache_data, origin=cache_index, model=model)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 388, in parse_sources_data
    raise InvalidData('line:\n\t%s\n%s' % (line, e), origin=origin)
rosdep2.core.InvalidData: line:
    yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml osx
unsupported pickle protocol: 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/rospack.py", line 59, in init_rospack_interface
    lookup = _get_default_RosdepLookup(Options())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 130, in _get_default_RosdepLookup
    verbose=options.verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 633, in create_default
    sources = load_cached_sources_list(sources_cache_dir=sources_cache_dir, verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 533, in load_cached_sources_list
    return parse_sources_data(cache_data, origin=cache_index, model=model)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 388, in parse_sources_data
    raise InvalidData('line:\n\t%s\n%s' % (line, e), origin=origin)
rosdep2.core.InvalidData: line:
    yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml osx
unsupported pickle protocol: 4
[rospack] Error: could not call python function 'rosdep2.rospack.init_rospack_interface'
```

I have looked at the solutions of the same problem posted earlier, there were two of them but none of their solutions worked for me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307543/problem-with-rospack-depends1/) by [taraprasad73](https://answers.ros.org/users/38346/taraprasad73/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-11-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-04**:
Related / duplicate: #q234825.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would seem to be [ros-infrastructure/rosdep#379](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/379) and [ros/rospack#95](https://github.com/ros/rospack/issues/95).

A fix has been implemented (in [ros-infrastructure/rosdep#633](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/633)) and merged, but that may not have been released yet.

Just to confirm: what is the output of `python --version` on your system?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [taraprasad73](https://answers.ros.org/users/38346/taraprasad73/) on 2018-11-04**:
python --version returns Python 3.6.5

**Comment by [taraprasad73](https://answers.ros.org/users/38346/taraprasad73/) on 2018-11-04**:
So, this issue is due to the conflict between Python versions. Can you suggest any workaround to this problem, until the fix is released?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-04**:
Make sure `/usr/bin/env python` returns a v2 Python interpreter.